# Spilt Unit test and Integration test in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tdd, liquibase

Need General Idea

*What can qualify to be good unit test in spring boot?*

**Areas of discussion**

- Should we use `@Autowired` to call another class in unit test **or** everything use Mock.
- `@Mock` Vs `@MockBean`
- If we use `@Mock` and `@Autowired` together in Unit test class, can it be still a qualified to be unit test or becomes Integration test.

NOTE: Aware of `@RunWith` to make Integration and Remove Integration. My Question stress more about writing a good unit test in spring boot applications.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good practise to use @Mock for the dependencies while unit testing. you would not certainly need to load spring context to run your unit cases. When using Mocks, the test can be run independent of the spring context. @Autowired in unit testing slightly behaves more of an app integration testing where you are loading the spring context ,at least slice of it for the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a method like this `PerformPayment(double amount, PaymentService service);`

A unit test would be a test where you create a mock for the `service` argument.

An integration test would be a test where `you use an actual external service` so that you test if that service responds correctly to your input data.

If I go deeper in details

`Unit tests` are tests that the tested code is inside of the actual class. `Other dependencies of this class are mocked or ignored, because the focus is to test the code inside the class.`

`Integration tests` are tests that involve disk access, application service and/or frameworks from the target application. `The integration tests run isolated from another external service.`

**I will give an example.** You have a Spring application and you made a lot of unit tests to guarantee that the business logic is working properly. Perfect. But what kind of tests you have to guarantee:

Your application service can start

Your database entity is mapped correctly

You have all the necessary annotations working as expected

Your Filter is working properly

Your API is accepting some kind of data

Your main feature is really working in the basic scenario

Your database query is working as expected

Etc...

This can't be done with unit tests but you, as a developer, need to guarantee that all things are working too. This is the **objective of integration tests.**

The ideal scenario is the integration tests running independently from another external system that the application use in a production environment. You can accomplish that using Wiremock for Rest calls, a memory database like H2, mocking beans from some specific classes that call external systems, etc.

A little curiosity, Maven has a specific plugin for Integration Tests: the maven failsafe plugin, that executes test classes that the name ends with IT. Example: UserIT.java.

Read more by guru 
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationTest.html